# ERROR Invalid coordinate in positionRelativeToViewPoint:forCoordinate:inDirection

Tags: ios, core-plot

For some reason all of a sudden I get an error when making graphs with coreplot.
In the method

```
-(void)positionRelativeToViewPoint:(CGPoint)point forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate inDirection:(CPTSign)direction
```

the direction becomes invalid (it is not a CPTSignNone, CPTSignNegative nor CPTSignPositive). 
My code can be found on Github (https://github.com/anneEverars/Vittles).

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found out that the problem was with some changes I made to the project settings and not the code. By replacing this to the previous settings, everything got fixed!

Comment: Can you specify, otherwise your self answer is useless.